# What does the accept() method of ASTNode do and how does it use the ASTVisitor?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

What does the `accept` method of ASTNode do (The javadoc didn't help too much...) and when will the `visit(Expression node)` method be called?
Here is an example code of how I need to use it:

```
final List<Expression> listi = new ArrayList<Expression>();
String stringi = opi.generate(entryContract, true_false_maybe);
// stringi representes an expression, for example "g!=h".
parser.setSource(stringi.toCharArray());
unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); 
ASTNode astRoot = unit.getRoot();
astRoot.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
 public boolean visit(Expression node) {
  listi.add(node);
  return true;
 }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `Expression` class is a subtype of the `ASTNode` class, and the `ASTVisitor` class present other visit methods (which surely will be empty), accepting as an argument other `ASTNode` subclasses.

It's an implementation of the [GoF Visitor Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) (also described at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

The `accept` method on `ASTNode` will just invoke the `visit` method on the visitor implementation, passing itself as parameter for the `visit` method.